# Python JSON Loads with mixture of Hex and UTF 8 chars in string

Tags: python, json

I am scraping a site and it is returning a string that has a mixture of UTF8 and hex

Below is a sample

```
\x5B\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x2218210\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2272\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22BlockedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.789000015258789\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.6409999847412109\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.031017674133181572\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Cristian\x20Gamboa\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x22855\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222014\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x224633\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22West\x20Bromwich\x20Albion\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20City\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x223\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222014\x2D12\x2D26\x2015\x3A00\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3Anull,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22TakeOn\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x2257726\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2284\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22MissedShots\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.74\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.6070000076293945\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.022933539003133774\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Cristian\x20Gamboa\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22a\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x22855\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222015\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x22112\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Stoke\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22West\x20Bromwich\x20Albion\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x220\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222015\x2D08\x2D29\x2018\x3A00\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3Anull,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22BallRecovery\x22\x7D\x5D
```

If I have it print out the output to my console then I copy and paste it like so

```
json.loads([sample from above])
```

It works no problem

But I cant do that for every response it would take forever,
So I use beautiful soup to load the webpage and then find the string that contains what I need I load that into variable data, when I say print data I get the EXACT string as shown in the example above, but json loads does not work

```
import re
import json


x =re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", modify, re.DOTALL) 
data = x[0] 
json.loads(data)
or
json.loads(str(data))
```

both return an error of

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, please edit your question, add some code styling and provide a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently your question is very low quality. Also I can not reproduce that `json.loads('\x5B\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x2232522\x22,\x22minute')` is working. For me that throws a ValueError (cause it is not json) in Python 2.7 and 3.8

Comment: Thanks I have updated with a sample cprrect sample and code styling

Comment: `when I say print data I get the EXACT string as shown in the example above` I don't think so, maybe it looks the same on the console but it is not the same. Please use a debugger and compare the content of the variable. For example you include the line break with re.DOTALL but I think the json parser will throw an error on line break.